# How to change component selection type in edit mode in Blender 2.8 alpha?

Tags: interface, selection-tools, shortcut

Anyone know what happened to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut? Usually when in object mode it switches to weight paint mode, and when in edit mode it offers a menu called "mesh select mode" to choose between vertex, edge, or face selection.

That used to work fine on last weeks builds of 2.8, but today I've downloaded the new build and now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only shows a menu to change between "object interaction mode" (object mode, weight paint, sculpting, etc..).

Note: Tried exporting the key configuration file from a previous build where this was working, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with unfinished experimental versions of Blender

Answer (score 2):

First of, Blender 2.8 is in development. It's an unfinished alpha product constantly changing hour after hour. So if you're not prepared to constantly change with it, you should wait for the 2.80 release.

---

For now, the default keymap is one of the things currently being worked on. You can follow the advancement  [on the tracker here](https://developer.blender.org/T55162). There is also a list of shortcut being made [here](https://developer.blender.org/T55194).

The previous component menu seems to be gone for now. Though you can use <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to switch between each of them.